# How do you properly declare enum type in a DefinitelyTyped library?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, enums, definitelytyped

I am trying to create a type library for submission to DefinitelyTyped and have come across a bit of a hurdle.

My setup is as follows

- a type definition in the node_modules@types folder

```
    // The actual type definition file
    // index.d.ts (in node_modules/@types/enum-test)
    export enum EnumType {
        TYPE_A = "TYPEA",
        TYPE_B = "TYPEB"
    }
    export interface SomeInterface {
        stringAttribute: string;
        enumAttribute?: EnumType;
    }
```

- a consumer of this definiton, typescript app

```
    // The consumer of this type definition file
    // service.ts
    import express from 'express';
    import {SomeInterface, EnumType} from 'enum-test'
    
    let myObject: SomeInterface = {
        stringAttribute: "Awsome",
        enumAttribute: EnumType.TYPE_A,
    }
    const app = express();
    app.listen(3000, () => {
    
        console.log('The application is listening on port 3000!');
        console.log('Account is' + myObject.stringAttribute);
    })
```

The type script compiler compiles this OK, however when I run this I get the error
`Error: Cannot find module 'enum-test'`

If I remove `enumAttribute` from `myObject`, OR if I change
`export enum EnumType ...` to `export const enum EnumType` it all works.

I cannot change this to `const enum` because the linter for DefinitlyTyped packages does not allow it. Changing the tslint.json is not an option since one of the criteria for submission of a DefinitelyTypes package is to only use this tslint.json

```
    { 
        "extends": "dtslint/dt.json"
    }
```

**So, the question is how do you define enums in a DefinitelyTyped package so I can use them AND it is acceptable for DefinitelyTyped repository?**

Comment: There are no enums in JavaScript. They are a concept of TypeScript. So having an enum in your type defintion is probably not right. I guess that what the library is exporting there is an object and you need to type that. Could you post or link to the code of the library you are trying to create type definitions for?

Comment: Thanks @KrisztiánBalla . You are quite right. I have since updated the definitions to do just that. Btw, the library is published here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/consumer-data-standards